# HP Fortify issue- XML External Entity Injection

Tags: java, xml, security, fortify

I solved XML External Entity Injection with DocumentBuilderFactory class using below code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
dbf.setXIncludeAware(false);
dbf.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
```

Now I have to resolve this XML External Entity Injection coming when I am using TransformerFactory class.

I could not find these methods in the TransformerFactory.

> setXIncludeAware() and setExpandEntityReferences()

what are the alternatives for this in TransformerFactory class? is there any other way to pass HP fortify for this?

thanks in advance